# Is this an error in the VB.NET compiler or by design?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, compiler-construction

I've found a difference in overload resolution between the C# and the VB-compiler. I'm not sure if it's an error or by design:

```
Public Class Class1
    Public Sub ThisBreaks()

        ' These work '
        Foo(Of String)(Function() String.Empty) 'Expression overload '
        Foo(String.Empty) 'T overload '

        ' This breaks '
        Foo(Function() String.Empty)
    End Sub

    Public Sub Foo(Of T)(ByVal value As T)

    End Sub

    Public Sub Foo(Of T)(ByVal expression As Expression(Of Func(Of T)))

    End Sub
End Class
```

Note that it doesn't matter if the overloaded Foo-methods are defined in VB or not. The only thing that matters is that the call site is in VB.

The VB-compiler will report an error:

> Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Foo' is most specific for these arguments:

*'Public Sub Foo(Of String)(expression As System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of System.Func(Of String)))': Not most specific.*

*'Public Sub Foo(Of )(value As )': Not most specific.*

---

Adding the C# code which works for comparison:

```
class Class1
{
    public void ThisDoesntBreakInCSharp()
    {
        Foo<string>(() => string.Empty);
        Foo(string.Empty);
        Foo(() => string.Empty);
    }

    public void Foo<T>(T value)
    {

    }

    public void Foo<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expression)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: another one of those very subtle language/compiler differences, I guess...

Comment: Doh, I guess I cut and pasted before I added the C# equivalent... Will edit now...

Comment: +1, nice question illustrating one of the shortcomings of the VB.NET compiler compared to C#. Maybe someone with better understanding of how those compilers work might provide an educated answer.

Comment: VB.NET allows you to omit the generic type argument and infer it by itself, as long as it is capable of doing so without ambiguity. The error, as Patrik Hägne pointed earlier, is that there is no clear distinction in this case due to overloads ("not most specific").

Comment: @Pauli: I've found a couple of compiler bugs before so it's not THAT unlikely.

Comment: @M.A. Of course, I understand the error. The question is WHY does the compiler not choose the expression overload as the most specific since that's exactly what the C# compiler does.

Comment: Good question indeed. +1

Comment: Perhaps the VB designer decided to err on the side of caution and show an error instead of silently choosing a potentially wrong/unintended overload, because they don't expect programmers to understand the subtleties of overloading.

Comment: Type inference with lamdas is a bit ugly in any case. A function signature doesn't have a specific delegate type associated with it, a lamda can be converted to both a delegate and to an expression, and it supports some difficult(reverse direction, i.e. from the function parameter to the lamda) type inference.

Comment: @Patrick the c# and vb.net compiler are note constructed out of the same language specification so what can seem like an error at first glance usually has a natural explanation when you start going through the documents.

Comment: @Pauli Hence: "I'm not sure if it's an error or by design." I'm pretty sure now that it's by design, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure I've found the reason for this and it is not a short coming of the VB-compiler but it is a short coming of the C# compiler.

Consider the following which is legal in VB:

```
Dim foo = Function() String.Empty
```

The equivalent would not be legal in c#:

```
var foo = () => string.Empty;
```

So, type inference is a bit stronger in VB, because of this the argument in the example `Function() String.Empty` can be inferred to `Function(Of String)` which would be applicable to the `Foo(Of T)(ByVal value As T)` overload.

In C# this can not happen since the `() => string.Empty` can never be inferred without context, it can be inferred in the expression overload but not in the T-overload.

Comment: not sure if this should be called a 'shortcoming of the C# compiler'... :-). Why is it better to infer to `Func(Of T)` and not `Expression(Of Func(Of T))` ?

Comment: It's not better to infer Func(Of T), it's just that C# can't infer the type at all without context. That's why the Foo(Of T)(ByVal value As T) is never considered by C#. If it's a shortcoming or not might be debated but it's at least less capable.

Answer (score 5):

Ignoring for the moment the assumption that "if the C# compiler does it, it must be right, therefore it's a bug in the VB compiler". I can immediately see the ambiguity:

```
Foo(Function() String.Empty)
```

Could invoke the `T` version, substituting `Func(Of String)` for T. Or it could reclassify the single line lambda into an expression tree, and invoke the `Expression(Of Func(Of String))` method. There's no reason one should be preferred over the other, and in fact VB is stopping you from proceeding without forcing you to specify which one you want.

Comment: I can see the ambiguity too, I never stated that the C# compiler was right, I'm asking the question if the VB-compiler is wrong or not. If the answer to that question is - no, it's not wrong - then the C# compiler might be wrong.

Comment: I think neither is "wrong". My guess is that the specification for overload resolution has some subtle differences.

Comment: That's my guess too. I'd just like to verify that assumption.

Comment: @CodeInChaos - the specifications appear, superficially, to be quite a lot different. I'm trying to parse them out at the moment to work out if they're actually saying similar things or not.

Comment: I guess this (from the VB-spec) comes into play: Type argument inference occurs before expression reclassification is performed on lambda methods or method pointers in the argument list... I'm not sure what the C# spec says.

Comment: I agree with you on the ambiguity and if you do you'd also agree that the following line must be ambiguous: Dim foo = Function() String.Empty, it could be interpreted as Func(Of String) or as Expression(Of Func(Of String)) but the VB-compiler chooses the func-interpretation. This is what the whole issue boils down to, the VB-compiler finds my example above ambiguous because it does NOT find Function() String.Empty ambiguous. I think I prefer the C# compiler in this case, though I'm not saying any of them are wrong.

Comment: @Patrik - I disagree, that line of VB isn't ambiguous, because we're not attempting overload resolution at that time, nor dealing with reclassification. There's nothing in that line to prompt the VB compiler to consider reclassifying it as an Expression.

Comment: @Damien - You're free to disagree, I'm just saying that the VB-team and the C# team obviously disagree on this. I think I'm on the C#-side in this particular case.