# Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Any' is most specific for these arguments

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

suddenly existing code is started giving below error. Strange thing is, This code works fine on other machine.

```
Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Any' is most specific for these arguments:
Extension method 'Public Function Any() As Boolean' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable': Not most specific.
Extension method 'Public Function Any() As Boolean' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable': Not most specific.
```

on line sites.any() in below code

```
Dim sites As IEnumerable(Of A.Commerce.ContentManagement.Entity.Site) = SiteManager.GetSitesByType(SiteType.Website)

If ((Not IsNothing(sites)) And sites.Any()) Then
```

I saw resolutions in some post which says something wrong in call syntax. but in my case, this works fine on another computer. Have I done something wrong with my machine? Only thing I remember that I have done some install/uninstall with GAC. Can anyone please help?

edit::

Just observed that its specific to solution and machine combination. because below code works fine with .Any() function on separate project.

```
' Create a list of Integers.    
Dim numbers As New List(Of Integer)(New Integer() {1, 2})

' Determine if the list contains any items. 
Dim hasElements As Boolean = numbers.Any()

' Display the output. 
Dim text As String = IIf(hasElements, "not ", "")
MsgBox("The list is " & text & "empty.")
```

edit 2 : It is giving error with all Linq methods. Like no accessible 'First', no accessible 'FirstOrDefault', no accessible 'Where' etc etc... Any help??

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a short but complete program? Is it possible that you've got a reference to two different `System.Linq.Enumerable` types, e.g. via LINQBridge? Do other LINQ methods work?

Comment: try `(Not IsNothing(sites) AndAlso sites.Any())` With just `And` code `sites.Any()` will execute anyway, which can raise this error

Comment: Does "works fine on other machine" mean it compiles there or is this a run-time error?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Sure. I will try to reproduce and post it again. I am not exactly aware of LINQBridge. we are using nuget in our project. I do not find System.Linq.Enumerable reference in my project but I do find reference of System.xml.Linq. can you please suggest how to make sure I am not using multiple reference?

Comment: Well it would be helpful if you would post a list of assembly references. Note that system.xml.linq is entirely separate - that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: Fabio and @adrianm: but this code compiles good on another machine. And this gives me compile time error on my machine.

Comment: Well that's a *lot* of assemblies... It'll really help if you can cut this down to a much smaller program.

Comment: @JonSkeet okay. let me do this and post it again.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have attached screenshot for your better view. Microsoft.Csharp can cause problem by any chance? Because I tried installing nuget package initially which gave me error saying 'Failed to add reference  to Microsoft.Csharp. Please make sure that it is in global assembly cache.

Comment: Why do you need a reference to `Microsoft.CSharp` at all, if this is a VB project?

Comment: @JonSkeet When I tried to install one of the nuget packages, it gave me that error. I guess that package might be using this dll internally. I have manually added reference to this, then only I was able to install nuget package.

Comment: Somehow I feel this post is relevant to this.. :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620704/is-this-an-error-in-the-vb-net-compiler-or-by-design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I resolved... :)

`System.Core.dll` was the main culprit. Somehow my solution started referencing `version 3.5 of System.Core.dll` though my solution targets .Net Framework 4.5. Version 3.5 has different implementation for System.Linq.Enumerable functions.

Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar situation and discovered two things. I was following a tutorial where someone had used a generic class to demonstrate use of model and view. He then went on to demonstrate how to generate the view from a database.

However, he did not mention that the previous class, which had properties like firstname, surname, etc, was to be removed since these are now reflected in the datacontext created from the linq to sql class.

I discovered that it is what was causing multiple referencing and once i removed the previous class, everything works just fine.